# Location of the clipboard history managed by Klipper

Tags: kubuntu, clipboard, clipboard-manager

Where does Klipper store the clipboard history?
I'm using Kubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Look in `~/.local/share/klipper` for something like `history2.lst` which isn't a plain text file.

Comment: @DKBose: Could you please post that as a (partial) answer? If you want to make it easier for other's to fill in the blanks you can post it as a community-wiki answer. (PSA: [Please stop posting half answers and dumb advice as comments](/q/2281/175814))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you've copied something. Immediately open a terminal and run

```
find -newerat 2 | grep klipper
```

You'll get a list of folders and files which klipper has modified looking something like

```
./.local/share/klipper
./.local/share/klipper/history2.lst
```

Obviously, `history2.lst` will be of interest to you.

Unfortunately,

```
file history2.lst
```

shows that `history2.lst` is a data file. You thus need to view it preferably with the application that created it.

To do so and even to edit or delete individual entries in your clipboard, just left-click on the clipboard icon in your plasma panel to access klipper's tools.

[image: klipper]